# Generator of the group $\langle\mathbb Z,+\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have seen that the generator of the group $\langle \mathbb Z,+\rangle$ is $1$, i mean $\langle \mathbb Z , +\rangle=\langle 1\rangle$. But why is this the case? How can we generate negative numbers with just using $1$? I mean, $1$, $1+1=2$, $1+1+1=3$, $\ldots$ and so on, but how do we get negative integers? Thanks

Comment: $1$ generates $\mathbb Z$ means that every element of $\mathbb Z$ is a multiple of $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: You forgot that you also get inverses. More generally, if $G$ is a group written multiplicatively, and $g\in G$, then $$\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}=\{\ldots,g^{-2},g^{-1},1_G,g,g^2,\ldots\}\;,$$ not just $$\{g^n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}=\{g,g^2,g^3,\dots\}\;,$$ or even that together with the identity element.

Comment: Oh, yes i think i forgot the fact that, Z+ is not a subgroup of Z, because it does not contain inverses. T find the smallest subgroup containing 1, we need -1 in the group, so by having 1 and -1, we can generate Z, right?

Comment: Again I ask myself: Why are comments used for answers?

Comment: @Martin: Because when I commented, I hadn’t enough time available to write it up properly as an answer. In principle it was also an opportunity for the OP to write up an answer, though since I didn’t think to mention the possibility, it was never very likely.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott That's actually not a bad idea. I might just do that in the future myself! You're breathing a whole new meaning to answers/suggestions in comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Brian noted in the comments above:

Multiplicatively, for a group $G$ generated by $g$:

$$G = \langle g\rangle=\{g^n\mid n\in\mathbb Z\}=\{\ldots,\, g^{-2},\, g^{-1},\, g^0 = e ,\; g,\; g^2,\,\ldots\},$$ since a group is closed under the multiplication AND closed under taking inverses.

We can express this additively, as well: for a group $G$ under addition generated by $g$:

$$G = \langle g\rangle=\{n g \mid n\in\mathbb Z\} = \{\ldots,\, -2g,\; -1g, \; 0g = e,\; g,\; 2g,\; \ldots\},$$

So for $(\mathbb Z, +)$, which, as you correctly note, is generated by $1$:

$$ 
\begin{align}\mathbb Z = \langle 1\rangle=\{n\cdot 1\mid n\in\mathbb Z\} 
& =\{\ldots,\;-2\cdot 1,\; -1\cdot 1,\;  0\cdot 1,\; 1\cdot 1,\; 2\cdot 1,\; \ldots \} \\ \\
& = \{\ldots, -2,\; -1,\; 0, \;1,\; 2,\,\ldots\}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Nicely done Amy. Brian hit it great.